# Laravel Eloquent trying to retreive all answers with the same foreign key in a table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a project in which I have 3 tables a questions table an answers table and a users table

In the Questions table I have the following:

```
 Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('question');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

In the Users table I have the following:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('district')->nullable();
            $table->string('area')->nullable();
            $table->string('committee')->nullable();
            $table->string('position')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

In the Answers table I have the following:

```
Schema::create('answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('question_id');
            $table->foreign('question_id')->references('id')->on('questions');
            $table->string('answer');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

And those are the models

```
class Answer extends Model
{
    public function user(){
      return $this->hasOne('App\User');
    }
    
    public function question(){
      return $this->hasOne('App\Question');
    }
}

class Question extends Model
{
    public function answer(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Answer');
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','district','area','committee','position',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function answer(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Answer');
    }
}
```

Based on my structure the answers table will have entries with each row made of the user_id and his answer to one question and in the following row the other question

How can I retrieve the data in a table where it shows me in the first row the user in a column with all 4 of his answers in the following 4 columns?

Comment: do you have your relationship defined in models?>

Comment: yess I will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

First `Answer` model should be like this. As it's one-to-many.

```php
class Answer extends Model
{
    public function user(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    
    public function question(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Question');
    }
}
```

And then you can get data like this:

```php
$results = User::with('answer')->first();
// this should give the first `user` with all the answers that belongs to the user.

$results = User::with('answer')->get();
// this should give you all the users.
```

let's say you need all users and all the answers.

```php
foreach ($results as $user) {
    echo $user->name;
    
    foreach ($user->answer as $value) {
     echo $value->answer;
   }
}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: yes but if I need to deploy each user with all his answers I use $results = User::with('answer')->get() or all()?

Comment: and what would be the @foreach if the row should be in the form of user | answer 1 | answer 2 | answer 3 | answer 4

Comment: one more things the answers are coming in a random order what should I add to have the answers of each question under each other for example the user1  | answer 1 for Q1 | answer 2 for Q2 2 and the next row same thing but for user 2

Comment: @GeorgioBilani what are you talking about, there is no `question` from the query.

Comment: in the answers table there is a foreign key for the table questions to assign each answer at a question so the answer table will look like id | User_id | Question_id | answer how can I based on what you have given me in the foreach get the $value->answer in order which means question 1-2-3 because right now I am receiving the $value->answer based on order in DB so if a user answered the questions in order they will display in order if the user answered the question 2-1-3 the answers won't appear in order